# How to print '\n' in argv in python

Tags: python, argv

```
>>> print('\naaa','bbbb\n ccc')

aaa bbbb
 ccc
>>> def myprint(*argv):
...    print(argv)
...
>>> myprint('\naaa','bbbb\n ccc')
('\naaa', 'bbbb\n ccc')
```

how to make myprint have same output as print?

Comment: Add a line in function to replace the \ with \\ as argv= argv.replace("\","\\")

Comment: What's the point? `myprint = print`? You could use the star operator again, `print(*argv)` but I'm not sure why we're doing this in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an asterisk (`*`) to `print(argv)`. This unpacks the tuple and passed them as arguments to print, which prints them.

```py
def myprint(*argv):
    print(*argv)
myprint('\naaa','bbbb\n ccc')
```

Output:

```
aaa bbbb
 ccc
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
def myprint(*argv):
    print(' '.join(argv))
myprint('\naaa', 'bbbb\n ccc')
```

Comment: you could do this, but `*argv` is shorter (what I did in my answer)